# Objective C IPhone Subclassing UITextField catch Value Changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, overriding, subclass

I have subclassed UITextField so I can create some custom behaviours for it. Here are my classes:

DataboundTextField.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestEntities.h"

@interface DataboundTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate> {
NSString *valueMember;
NSString *displayValueMember;
ODataObject *boundEntity;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *valueMember;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *displayValueMember;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ODataObject *boundEntity;
-(void)SetupDataBinding:(ODataObject*)oDataEntity ValueMember:(NSString*)valMemberID    DisplayValueMember:(NSString*)disValMember;

@end
```

DataboundTextField.m

```
#import "DataboundTextField.h"

@implementation DataboundTextField

@synthesize valueMember;
@synthesize displayValueMember;
@synthesize boundEntity;

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
{
    self.delegate = self;
}

return self;
}



-(void)SetupDataBinding:(ODataObject*)oDataEntity ValueMember:(NSString*)valMemberID DisplayValueMember:(NSString*)disValMember{

}

-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
return YES;
}

@end
```

How do I go about overriding the ValueChanged event? I cannot seem to catch it however I try. All I want to do is wack one of these subclassed Textfields on a view and catch that event and handle it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with the UITextField, you may not need to subclass. A lot can be done with the UITextFieldDelegate methods.

Comment: I want this class to be reusable throughout the entire project so i dont think using a delegate will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `UITextFieldDelegate`, you can use

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

> The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character.

Make sure you set the `delegate` property of your `UITextField`:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to fire. Ive edited my post to show you what i have now.

Comment: Are you setting the UITextField's delegate?

Comment: Ive now overridden the initwithcoder and set the delegate as itself (changed code in post to show what ive done). But now when I go to click in the textbox at runtime the whole app hangs???

Comment: anyway, whats the Difference between '[super setDelegate:self];' and '[self setDelegate:self];' ?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have used to allow only certain characters, as well as how many characters are allowed for a textField:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    /*  allow only these characters in the textField  */   
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890|:.@~_-+#!{}%*"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    /*  choose how many characters the textField can have  */
    NSUInteger newLength = [theTextField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 28) ? NO : YES;
}
```